# nodejs that doesn't require libatomic

Tags: node.js

The latest version of nodejs on linux armv7 says "missing libatomic.so.1". Older versions don't give that error. Does someone know the last version that didn't require libatomic installed separately (i.e. it included everything)?

Installing nodejs on a small ARMv7 system running a custom linux distro.